# Converting Excel file to csv using to_csv, removes leading zeros even when cells are formatted to be string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

When I try to convert my excel file to csv, using to_csv function, all my item number that has 1 leading 0, loses it except for the very first row.

I have a simple forloop that iterates through all cells and converts cell values to string so I have no idea why only first row gets converted to csv format correctly with the leading 0.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = str(cell.value)

pd.read_excel('example.xlsx').to_csv('result.csv', index=False, line_terminator = ',\n')
```

e.g. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njb3n.png (won't let me directly add image but it shows the following in excel)

```
0100,03/21/2019,4:00,6:00
0101,03/21/2019,4:00,6:00
0102,03/21/2019,4:00,8:00
```

turns into:

```
0100,03/21/2019,4:00,6:00,
101,03/21/2019,4:00,6:00,
102,03/21/2019,4:00,8:00,
```

What can I do to have 0 in front of all the first items in csv?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have not header in excel file: the name by default of columns is 0,1,... and so on

if you want to keep the zero at column 0 for example, just do:

```
pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', header=None, dtype={0:str})\
  .to_csv('result.csv', index=False, line_terminator = ',\n'
```

if you havent header and you dont precise header=None, the first row is the header. dtype={0:str} indicates the column 0 will be str.

be carefull when you save the excel file to csv, the header is saved (here with your options), the first row will be 0,1,..  (name of columns)

if you dont want header to csv file use:

```
pd.read_excel('e:/test.xlsx', header=None, dtype={0:str})\
  .to_csv('e:/result.csv', index=False, header=False, line_terminator = ',\n')
```

Comment: I noticed to_csv did not have dtype as one of its params and did not think about adding it in read_excel. Thank you so much!